# Kafka losing messages under intense stress - normal?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

A few details about the context. I have an application with the following flow:

1. Put 10k messages in the input topic.
2. Kafka App 1 will consume messages from input topic and write to mid topic (using exactly once with an idempotent producer writing consumer offsets for input topic plus message to mid topic)
3. Kafka App 2 will consume messages from mid topic and write to output topic (using exactly once with an idempotent producer writing consumer offsets for mid topic plus message to output topic)
4. Expect 10k messages in the output topic.

So I've configured both Kafka App 1 and App 2 to have exactly once processing, everything went well when processing messages and:

1. killing with -9 Zk instances and starting again the instance
2. killing with -9 Kafka brokers and starting again the broker
3. killing with -9 Kafka App 1 and starting again the app
4. killing with -9 Kafka App 2 and starting again the app

In above 4 cases exactly once is achieved and I don't lose messages and I don't have duplicates.

However when processing messages and randomly killing with -9 Zk Instances and Kafka Brokers (in parallel), I've saw that I lose messages.

Is this expected?

Comment: Looks like there is a race condition, where all brokers ack the message, but they all get killed simultaneously with -9, and they don't have time to flush the message from memory to disk.